# avoid nesting foreach loop in java

Tags: java, foreach, nested, processing-efficiency

It's been about 20 years since I have taken a coding class.  I pick it up again from time to time for fun, but my code is clunky & inefficient.

I have an array with just over 400 elements.  I currently have nested foreach loops operating over that array.

```
import acm.program.ConsoleProgram;
import java.awt.Color;
import acm.io.IODialog;
import java.text.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.*;

/** Tests to see if user color matches sample colors */

public class test extends ConsoleProgram

{

   //defining sample colors

   Color[] dmc =
   {
      new Color(255,255,255),
      new Color(148,91,128),
      new Color(206,148,186),
      new Color(236,207,225),
      new Color(243,218,228),

   };

 public void run()
 {
    average();

 }

 //averages three colors, then tests for match to given color

 public void average()
 {

    //asks for user color
    IODialog dialog = new IODialog();
    int stitchRed= dialog.readInt("Enter red value: ");
    int stitchGreen= dialog.readInt("Enter green value: ");
    int stitchBlue= dialog.readInt("Enter blue value: ");
    Color stitchColor= new Color(stitchRed,stitchGreen,stitchBlue);

    //gets averages for dmc colors
    for (Color i:dmc)
    {
       for (Color j:dmc)
       {
          for (Color k:dmc)
          {
              int indexI = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(i);
              int indexJ = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(j);
              int indexK = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(k);
              if(indexI <= indexJ && indexJ <= indexK)
              {
                 int iRed = i.getRed();
                 int jRed = j.getRed();
                 int kRed = k.getRed();
                 int iGreen = i.getGreen();
                 int jGreen = j.getGreen();
                 int kGreen = k.getGreen();
                 int iBlue = i.getBlue();
                 int jBlue = j.getBlue();
                 int kBlue = k.getBlue();
                 int redAverage = (iRed+jRed+kRed)/3;
                 int greenAverage = (iGreen+jGreen+kGreen)/3;
                 int blueAverage = (iBlue+jBlue+kBlue)/3;
                 Color colorAverage = new Color(redAverage,greenAverage,blueAverage);

                 //tests to see if any thread average equals user color
                 if (colorAverage.equals(stitchColor))
                 {
                    println("The color match is: " + i + ", " + j + ", " + k);
                 }
            }
         }
       }
     }

     println("no more matches");
   }
 }
```

This compiles fine, but runs REALLY slowly.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?
Possibly a way to get around nesting - something to the effect of:

for( Color i,j,k:dmc)

?

Comment: what is your expectation? What are you trying to do with your code?

Comment: Depending on your use case, this code might be parallelizable, so it could run really quickly, but you need to tell us more about what you want to achieve.

Comment: you could get some speed by 1: initially converting your array to an ArrayList, 2: checking the first 2 items for equality. (based on your code if they dont check out why bother) and you could save yourself some millieseconds. :)

Comment: I have a library of accessible colors.  I'm trying to find out whether any three colors from the list average together to match a color provided by the user, or the closest possible match.

Comment: Did you run it ? It seems that `int jGreen = j.getGreen();` is missing.

Comment: transcription error.  I can only run it on my other laptop, which doesn't connect to the internet.  I retyped it all by hand in the comments and must have skipped over a line.  Yes, it runs.

Answer (score 1):

(I can't test and debug the code since it is not an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), so I appologies for any errors)

Consider the following, see comments for details:

```
Color[ ] dmc = {element1, element2, ...};

for( int i =0; i < dmc.length ; i++ )
 {
    
    //iterate only on values >= i 
   for( int j = i; j< dmc.length; j++ )
   {
       //loop only on values >= j
       for( int k = j; k < dmc.length ; k++ )
       {
        
           //not needed, you already have i, j, k 
           //int indexI = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(i);
           //int indexJ = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(j);
           //int indexK = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(k);
          
           
           //condition is not needed. Allways true. 
           //if( indexI <= indexJ && indexJ <= indexK ) { }
           
           //bunch of code...
```

**EDIT:** A short demo to print out only the wanted incidences:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Color[ ] dmc = {Color.AQUA, Color.AZURE, Color.BEIGE, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE,
                    Color.BROWN, Color.CHOCOLATE, Color.CYAN,  Color.CRIMSON, Color.FUCHSIA};

            for( int i =0; i < dmc.length ; i++ )
             {

                System.out.printf("\n >>>>>> i= %s", i);
                //iterate only on values >= i
               for( int j = i; j< dmc.length; j++ )
               {
                   System.out.printf("\n         j= %s",j);

                   //loop only on values >= j
                   for( int k = j; k < dmc.length ; k++ )
                   {

                     System.out.printf("\n            k= %s",k);
                   }
               }
             }

        }
```

**EDIT II:** Following the MCVE posted I modified it by adding `fastEverage()` method, which should do the same calculation as `everage()` with less iterations.

On the single set of colors I checked, both methods have the same output:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Arrays;

/** Tests to see if user color matches sample colors */
public class Test

{

    //defining sample colors

    Color[] dmc =
        {
                new Color(255,255,255),
                new Color(148,91,128),
                new Color(206,148,186),
                new Color(236,207,225),
                new Color(243,218,228),

        };

    //averages three colors, then tests for match to given color
    public void average()
    {

        //asks for user color
        int stitchRed =  203; 
        int stitchGreen= 164;
        int stitchBlue= 189;

        Color stitchColor= new Color(stitchRed,stitchGreen,stitchBlue);

        //gets averages for dmc colors
        for (Color i:dmc)
        {
            for (Color j:dmc)
            {
                for (Color k:dmc)
                {
                    int indexI = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(i);
                    int indexJ = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(j);
                    int indexK = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(k);
                    if((indexI <= indexJ) && (indexJ <= indexK))
                    {
                        int iRed = i.getRed();
                        int jRed = j.getRed();
                        int kRed = k.getRed();
                        int iGreen = i.getGreen();
                        int kGreen = k.getGreen();
                        int jGreen = j.getGreen();
                        int iBlue = i.getBlue();
                        int jBlue = j.getBlue();
                        int kBlue = k.getBlue();
                        int redAverage = (iRed+jRed+kRed)/3;
                        int greenAverage = (iGreen+ jGreen + kGreen)/3;
                        int blueAverage = (iBlue+jBlue+kBlue)/3;

                        Color colorAverage = new Color(redAverage,greenAverage,blueAverage);

                        //tests to see if any thread average equals user color
                        if (colorAverage.equals(stitchColor))
                        {
                            System.out.println("The color match is: " + i + ", " + j + ", " + k);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("no more matches");
    }

    //averages three colors, then tests for match to given color
    public void fastEverage()
    {

        //asks for user color
        int stitchRed =  203; 
        int stitchGreen= 164;
        int stitchBlue= 189;
    
        Color stitchColor= new Color(stitchRed,stitchGreen,stitchBlue);

        Color colorI, colorJ, colorK;

        for( int i =0; i < dmc.length ; i++ )
        {

            colorI = dmc[i];

            //iterate only on values >= i
            for( int j = i; j< dmc.length; j++ )
            {

                colorJ = dmc[j];

                //loop only on values >= j
                for( int k = j; k < dmc.length ; k++ )
                {

                    colorK = dmc[k];

                    int iRed = colorI.getRed();
                    int jRed = colorJ.getRed();
                    int kRed = colorK.getRed();
                    int iGreen = colorI.getGreen();
                    int kGreen = colorK.getGreen();
                    int jGreen = colorJ.getGreen();
                    int iBlue = colorI.getBlue();
                    int jBlue = colorJ.getBlue();
                    int kBlue = colorK.getBlue();
                    int redAverage = (iRed+jRed+kRed)/3;
                    int greenAverage = (iGreen+ jGreen + kGreen)/3;
                    int blueAverage = (iBlue+jBlue+kBlue)/3;

                    Color colorAverage = new Color(redAverage,greenAverage,blueAverage);

                    //tests to see if any thread average equals user color
                    if (colorAverage.equals(stitchColor))
                    {
                        System.out.println("The color match is: " + colorI + ", " + colorJ + ", " + colorK);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("no more matches");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test().average();
        new Test().fastEverage();

    }
}
```

The run time difference between the 2 methods, on this test case, is significant:

> run time of everage() in nano seconds     84752814
>
> run time of fastEverage() in nano seconds 76497255

Comment: I started with this, but it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Why ? post an [MCVE] so we can find out why.

Comment: It has been 20 years since I took a coding class.  My code is very long and awkward - about 600 lines and there's not another part to it - just this function (well, two if you count it as >do they match & >what is the closest to a match).  Minimal is not really an option for this Frankenstein code.  There are likely other places where my code could be cleaned up, but after doing a few tests, this is the step that is hanging up my processor.  Also complicated by the fact that all of my programming software is on another laptop, which won't connect to the internet. I'm retyping everything.

Comment: Minimal means minimal for demonstrating the focused problem you need help with. I added a short demo ( [MCVE]) for the looping I proposed.

Comment: edited above with as pared down an example as I could.  The biggest difference/issue is that i,j, and k are colors.  You are treating them as ints in your example.  If I treat them as ints, then I have to somehow link that index number back to a color in the array in order to get the r,g,b values.  That was where I had issues compiling.  I can't remember how I had them associated before, but when a friend suggested a foreach loop instead of a for loop, that solved all of my indexing problems.

Comment: fastEverage() isn't running.  It's not recognizing Test() as a string.

Comment: I run it with no problems. What do you mean by "not running" ? Test() is not a String. Please copy the whole class as is, and run main(..)

Answer (score 1):

It's equals to @C0der's answer, Just uses the same names for question's var.

```
    for (int indexI = 0; indexI < dmc.length; indexI++) {
        Color i = dmc[indexI];
        for (int indexJ = indexI; indexJ< dmc.length; indexJ++) {
            Color j = dmc[indexJ];
            for (int indexK = indexJ; indexK< dmc.length; indexK++) {
                Color k = dmc[indexK];
                //....
            }
        }
    }
```

EDITED:

```
public void average() {
    //asks for user color
    IODialog dialog = new IODialog();
    int stitchRed = dialog.readInt("Enter red value: ");
    int stitchGreen = dialog.readInt("Enter green value: ");
    int stitchBlue = dialog.readInt("Enter blue value: ");
    Color stitchColor = new Color(stitchRed, stitchGreen, stitchBlue);
    for (int indexI = 0; indexI < dmc.length; indexI++) {
        Color i = dmc[indexI];
        for (int indexJ = indexI; indexJ < dmc.length; indexJ++) {
            Color j = dmc[indexJ];
            for (int indexK = indexJ; indexK < dmc.length; indexK++) {
                Color k = dmc[indexK];
                int iRed = i.getRed();
                int jRed = j.getRed();
                int kRed = k.getRed();
                int iGreen = i.getGreen();
                int jGreen = j.getGreen();
                int kGreen = k.getGreen();
                int iBlue = i.getBlue();
                int jBlue = j.getBlue();
                int kBlue = k.getBlue();
                int redAverage = (iRed + jRed + kRed) / 3;
                int greenAverage = (iGreen + jGreen + kGreen) / 3;
                int blueAverage = (iBlue + jBlue + kBlue) / 3;
                Color colorAverage = new Color(redAverage, greenAverage, blueAverage);
                //tests to see if any thread average equals user color
                if (colorAverage.equals(stitchColor)) {
                    System.out.println("The color match is: " + i + ", " + j + ", " + k);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("no more matches");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you filter out many combinations in the if-statement, one optimization would be to use for-loops only iterating over the elements you actually want to process instead of for-each-loops. E.g. i <= j means you can start the iteration in j at i.

Further improvements may very well be possible depending on your intentions as stated in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
for( x=1;x<401;x++ )
{
    Color j= dmc[x];
    Color k= dmc[x+1];
    int indexI = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(i);
    int indexJ = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(j);
    int indexK = Arrays.asList(dmc).indexOf(k);
    if( indexI <= indexJ && indexJ <= indexK )
    {
        //bunch of code...
```

or, you can try equals method defined in java.lang.Object. Hope this will help.

Comment: I need to allow for the possibilty that i,j, and k are all the same value.  Even if they are not, I need them to be *any* three elements of the array, not just adjacent elements.  I had originally left the index conditions off, but it seemed more efficient not to mentioned permutations.  I already know that if colors a,b, and c work, then colors c,b, and a will also work.

Comment: Do you want to pick any three elements and check them against each other or do you want to check each element against all the other elements in the array one by one?

Comment: Any three.  The program starts by prompting the user for a color (that they are trying to create).  The array is a list of embroidery thread colors, provided by the manufacturer.  The idea is to find out if it is possible to create the user color from mixing any three of the provided thread colors, using a simple mean.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. You can split the search. There is a possibility to find the match within the first search. If so, then you don't need to search the rest for a match.If not, you can move forward to search for the match.

```
int i,j,k;    
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
   for(j=i;j<100;j++){
      for(k=j;k<100;k++){
         //..do stuffs.....//
       } 
   }
}
if(matchnotfound){
  for(i=100;i<200;i++){
   for(j=i;j<200;j++){
      for(k=j;k<200;k++){
         //..do stuffs.....//
      } 
    }
  }
}
 if(matchnotfound){
  for(i=200;i<300;i++){
   for(j=i;j<300;j++){
      for(k=j;k<300;k++){
         //..do stuffs.....//
      } 
    }
  }
}
 if(matchnotfound){
  for(i=300;i<400;i++){
   for(j=i;j<400;j++){
      for(k=j;k<400;k++){
         //..do stuffs.....//
      } 
    }
  }
}
```